# ununtu bash session exiting on using tab key or some error commands

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu-16.04

Team, 
I am unable to catch this that only on first time when i issue a TAB key for command completion or any command that results in stderr, my bash session exits. When i login again and do the same exact it does not. Then after like some time, i start to the same exit behavour. Not sure what is wrong. In my ~/bashrc I have follwing info.

My scenario is I ssh from my macbook to a linux ubuntu and then i execute commands.

```
cat ~/.bashrc | grep PS
```

```
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
export PS1='\[\033[0;32m\]\[\033[0m\033[0;32m\]\u\[\033[0;36m\] @ \[\033[0;36m\]\h \w\[\033[0;32m\]$(__git_ps1)\n\[\033[0;32m\]└─\[\033[0m\033[0;32m\] \$\[\033[0m\033[0;32m\] ▶\[\033[0m\] '
```

```
cat ~/.bashrc | grep set
```

```
# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

```
 env | grep set
_VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_API= mkvirtualenv rmvirtualenv lsvirtualenv showvirtualenv workon add2virtualenv cdsitepackages cdvirtualenv lssitepackages toggleglobalsitepackages cpvirtualenv setvirtualenvproject mkproject cdproject mktmpenv mkvirtualenv rmvirtualenv lsvirtualenv showvirtualenv workon add2virtualenv cdsitepackages cdvirtualenv lssitepackages toggleglobalsitepackages cpvirtualenv setvirtualenvproject mkproject cdproject mktmpenv
```

```
env | grep PS
PS1=\[\033[0;32m\]\[\033[0m\033[0;32m\]\u\[\033[0;36m\] @ \[\033[0;36m\]\h \w\[\033[0;32m\]$(__git_ps1)\n\[\033[0;32m\]└─\[\033[0m\033[0;32m\] \$\[\033[0m\033[0;32m\] ▶\[\033[0m\]
```

Comment: I'm guessing that you sometimes source a script for some reason that happens to contain `set -e`. That explains the behavior of working fine for a while, and after this script has been sourced, the session exits after a subsequent command returns failure

Comment: Or may be there is a trap on ERR that forces bash to exit, something like `trap exit ERR`

Comment: I did check before executing TAB in ENV and there was no SET anywhere. and u mean trap in .bashrc? there is none.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My problem was that I called `set -e` in a script. Running `set +e` helped in my case.